# Is It necessary to restart logstash after modifying a dictionary_path file?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I used the following translate filter in logstash

```
translate {
   field => "countries"
   destination => "cities"
   dictionary_path  => "/home/rrr/cities.yml"
}
```

And I started logstash this way

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f $directory --path.settings=/etc/logstash -t
```

Everything went well and good.

My question is :

Would logstash will take into account any modification that I may do in the dictionary_path file ?
I means do I need to restart logstash after any edition on this file or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be necessary to restart logstash. There is a parameter in the configuration of the translate plugin, [refresh interval](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html#plugins-filters-translate-refresh_interval):

> refresh_interval
>
> Value type is number
>
> Default value is 300
>
> When using a dictionary file, this setting will indicate how frequently (in seconds) logstash will check the dictionary file for updates.